# Wordpress Front-end "Update" button that does the same as the back-end Update button

Tags: wordpress

I have to update a lot of custom fields from the front-end  single.php file.
One of these fields is 'price', and price is added to sql via a publish_post function **only** upon a post Update.

The goal is to have an Update button on the front end, that when pressed does the same as the back-end Update button.

The reason for that is even if i update the custom fields from the front-end, it does get written on the back end as expected. However, the post itself does not go through the "Update" or Publish process needed for the function in my functions.php file to fire.

Comment: **"They rely on a function that only runs when a post is Updated from the back-end."** Does that mean you are using the `post_save` hook or catching a post status transition?

What you're probably looking for is calling that function from the front end with `ajax`.

Comment: It is the  publish_post  hook.

Comment: Ajax is the way to go. I've provided a link in my answer to information on how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I do not have the knowledge of Ajax or Php to really understand that link, or how to put a working function together. I have pulled out all my hair over this and spend hours searching for solutions.

Comment: Did you write the function that hooks on `publish_post` and updates the custom fields? It's not much more of a stretch to get the **ajax** working. Granted, it will take time to read through. Why don't you give it a shot and then post back any questions/issues you have? :)

Answer (score 0):

**AJAX** is the solution you're looking for. [Here's](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) some information on how to do it in **WordPress**. :)

Answer (score 0):

Along with the publish_post hook, there is also an updated_post_meta hook just for when a custom field is updated.

So you can do:

```
add_action('updated_post_meta', 'updated_post_meta_fn', 10, 4);
```

And

```
function updated_post_meta_fn($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)
{

}
```

Comment: Once the post meta is updated from the front end, the publish_post hook should fire as well. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't think there's a way for the publish_post hook to fire upon a post meta update.  Can you have the updated_post_meta hook call a function similar to what your publish_post hook calls?